# Toggle browser full screen programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fullscreen

I'm using [Fullscreen API](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/) to toggle the full screen on the browser. It works but I have two issues:

1. When I'm in full screen, if I click on a link to go to another page (in my domain) the page leaves full screen. I want to continue in fullscreen mode.
2. In Chrome, the background doesn't fill the full height of the screen.

Those issues doesn't occur when I use full screen with F11 key.

There is some solution to those problem? Some othe API or work around?

**My javascript code:**

```
// toggle fullscren
function toggleFullScreen(element) {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
        !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
        launchFullScreen(element);
    } else {
        cancelFullscreen();
    }
}

// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullScreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}

// Whack fullscreen
function cancelFullscreen() {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
```

**My button to toggle full screen:**

```
<a onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.documentElement);">
    <img src="~/Content/icons/fullscreen-launch-icon.svg" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding your #1 question below is what Mozilla website says:

> In addition, navigating to another page, changing tabs, or switching to another application (using, for example, Alt-Tab) while in fullscreen mode **exits fullscreen mode** as well.

here is a link:
[Using Full Screen Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)